# Error when attempt to define a variable with two (or more) unlimited dimensions in netcdf4

Tags: netcdf

I am trying to define and write a variable that has two unlimited dimensions, using netcdf-c (version 4.8.1) like the following..

```
...
...
...

if ((rval = nc_create(out_file_nm, NC_CLOBBER, &out_ncid))) err(rval);


//// create netcdf dimensions
if ((rval = nc_def_dim(out_ncid, t_nm, NC_UNLIMITED, &out_t_dimid))) err(rval);
if ((rval = nc_def_dim(out_ncid, y_nm, nres_y      , &out_y_dimid))) err(rval);
if ((rval = nc_def_dim(out_ncid, x_nm, nres_x      , &out_x_dimid))) err(rval);
if ((rval = nc_def_dim(out_ncid, b_nm, NC_UNLIMITED, &out_b_dimid))) err(rval);

...
...
...
```

And I get the following error message.

```
Error: NetCDF: NC_UNLIMITED size already in use
```

As far as I know, starting with `netcdf-4`, I thought we can use multiple unlimited dimensions (link: https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/workshops/2010/netcdf4/UnlimDims.html).

I don't know what to do. The size of the values that I am trying to write is undetermined, it changes along the time dimension. So, I would really like to use two unlimited dimensions for this.

Does anyone have experience using multiple unlimited dimensions?

Comment: I'd try adding a mode option to your nc_create call.  NetCDF defaults to the classic data model w one unlimited dimension.  See: https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html#formatsdatamodelssoftwarereleases

Comment: It worked!! Thanks!

Comment: Great.  I turned it into an answer which you could accpet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try adding a mode option to your nc_create call. NetCDF defaults to the classic data model w one unlimited dimension. See: https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html#formatsdatamodelssoftwarereleases